# How many configuration levels can a SAS 9.4 installation have? Could I have a Lev10?

Tags: sas

[Installation Note 42839](http://support.sas.com/kb/42/839.html) suggests that an installation can have no more than 10 configuration levels, numbered 0-9. The note applies to SAS 9.2 and 9.3. Does this limit also apply to SAS 9.4?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Deployment Wizard still supports ten levels. See screenshot attached.

Regards,

Vasilij

[image]